# Prove that $f$ is linear

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, frechet-derivative

> Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{m} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ differentiable such that $\displaystyle f\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) = \frac{f(x)}{2}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$. Prove that $f$ is linear.

I'm trying to solve without using grad, because in my book, grad is only defined after. But I did not get a good idea, any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By induction we obtain
$$ f(x) = 2^n f\left( \frac{x}{2^n} \right) $$

Since $f$ is continuous
$$ f(0) = f\left( \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2^n} \right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2^n} f\left( 1 \right) = 0 $$

Since $f$ is differentiable
$$ f(x) = f(0) + df(0)(x) + r(x) $$

where
$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{r(x)}{\|x\|} = 0 $$

Therefore for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$
\begin{align}
f(x) &= 2^n f\left( \frac{x}{2^n} \right)\\
&= 2^n df(0)\left( \frac{x}{2^n} \right) + 2^n r \left( \frac{x}{2^n} \right)\\
&= df(0)(x) + \|x\| \frac{r \left( \frac{x}{2^n} \right)}{ \frac{\|x\|}{2^n} }
\end{align}

Taking the limit $n \to \infty$
$$ f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} 2^n f\left( \frac{x}{2^n} \right) = df(0)(x) + \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \|x\| \frac{r \left( \frac{x}{2^n} \right)}{ \frac{\|x\|}{2^n} } \right) = df(0)(x) $$

Hence $f$ is linear.

Comment: +1 Nice proof!!

Comment: +1. Very nice. I changed a bit the last equation if you don't mind.

Comment: @orangeskid Every improvement is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does this also hold for $f:\mathbb R^m\rightarrow\mathbb R^n$ with $f$ also being differentiable?